# Existence of solution of quasilinear transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Let $a,h\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$. I found out that a solution of the problem $u_t+a(u)u_x=0$, $u(0,x)=h(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ can be represented (implicitly) by $$u(t,x)=h(x-ta(u(t,x))).$$
Now, I have to prove that this solution $u$ exists as a function of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ iff $a(h(s))$ is a monotonically increasing function. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: **Hint**: Intermediate value theorem

Comment: @Mattos: Thanks, but to which function should it be applied? I did not get the idea - all my attempts failed so far.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518/418542) related post.